# Redirecting plain html to a reactjs page

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to react. I currently have a landing page that is basically written in plain html, css, ect. However, I have a Sign In button. When I click it, I would like to redirect to a new page which is written in react. Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: Are you working on development mode?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But not possible in 1 scenario.

**Possible scenario's,**

1. Your react app is hosted on server, in this case you can simply do this,

```
<a href="absolute_path_to_react_app" target="_blank">Sign in</a>
```

2. Your react app is not hosted on server, but running on local machine using `npm start`, in this case you can do this,

```
<a href="local_path_to_react_app" target="_blank">Sign in</a>
```

**Note::** `target="_blank"` is completely your wish as it take you to new page and not changing the current page.

**Not Possible scenario**

You are working on `development mode` on local machine, and your **react app in not running**. In this case you cannot redirect to react app as URL you try to visit is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Your new page(react) is like any other web-page such that when it's address would be loaded by the browser, it will run it - like any other web-page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple HTML webpage with a button and you have another HTML webpage with the React application rendered inside something, you just need a HTML anchor with a `href` to do the navigation:

```
<a href="/my-react-app">
  <button>Click me to navigate to React!</button>
</a>
```

If your React application is not rendering on the other webpage that is a completely different issue that I would open a new StackOverflow question for.

P.S.: Generally you would create your whole website in React (as a "single page app") and your landing page and every other page would be rendered in the React application. That is much more flexible and a better user experience.